# How to recover property from table into dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have some dataset `df` with the variables `state` and `status`. I wanted a table that gave me the frequency by both state and status, so I used `table(df$State, df$Status)`, and everything worked fine. Now, I want to make a US map using `plot_usmap` but I need a column with the two letter names of each state, which is in my table, but it is not a column, it is just the "index" although with strings instead of numbers. How do I take this not-a-column (I don't know what's the correct term for this part of the table), and turn it into a column I can use.

Table gave me the frequency data per state per status (the possible statuses are CHGOFF and P I F). I added the `Total` column manually. I need the column that has the names of the states.

[image]

Comment: Mostly those are rownames. Try `df$new_col <- rownames(df)`

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.